# The object becomes blur when entered into rendered view mode

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm a blender beginner. I experience some issue recently in rendered view mode.That is when I entered to rendered view mode the object becomes blur.By the way the render engine which I use is EEVEE. I need to fix this issue.So far I didn't find anything useful.I attached a screenshot herewith for the reference.
Thanks in advance.

[image: The issue with the object when entered into rendered view mode]

Comment: Try increasing the number of samples i.e. incresing the render option(which is currently 84)

Comment: @ParameshChandra Thanks a lot for the tip.I tried that.but unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue.Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The pixels can be artefacts of a GPU driver issue. Make sure you have the latest official driver installed from the hardware vendor. Some OEMs (dell or HP for example) install their own drivers which aren’t updated as often as the official drivers. If that is the case make sure you uninstall them before installing the official drivers.